# Why is my iOS Distribution Certificate 'Not in Keychain'?

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

So I created a distribution certificate and provisioning profile etc, and when I went to Xcode and checked my account preferences and chose Manage Certificates, it originally had no problem.  Now, when trying to upload my app to the store, it is grey and says, 'Not in Keychain'.  Just to add, when I clicked download on the Apple dev site for the distribution certificate, I did not get the popup that asks you to 'add' to keychain even after clicking on my download.  Is that what's wrong? How do I get that popup?  How can I fix this? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apple will not store your private key on the developer platform. You will always have to keep the private key in your keychain or some other safe place. If you see the message "Not in keychain" in the "Manage Certificates..." dialog of Xcode's Accounts preferences, it means that there is no copy of the certificate including the private key in your keychain. Do you have another account from where you can retrieve it? Then export from the keychain there and import it here where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

1，从Appledevelop 主要账户下载cer证书文件，运行安装
2，在钥匙串中找到证书导出.p12文件
3，下载需要的. mobileprovision 文件
4，放到目标Mac上运行这里两个
5，文件要在钥匙串 '登录目录下'
（* 选择钥匙串登录再运行.p12文件）

1. Download the CER certificate file from the appledevelop main account and run the installation
2. Find the certificate export. P12 file in the keychain
3. Download the required. Mobileprovision file
4. Put them on the target Mac and run these two
5. The file should be in the "login directory" of the keychain
   (* select the keyChain string to log in and then run the. P12 file)